# What is the probability that a randomly chosen fetal heartrate differs from the mean by more than 25 bpm?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

> Average fetal heartrate is $140$ bpm, with standard deviation of $12$ bpm. What is the probability that a randomly chosen fetal heartrate differs from the mean by more than $25$ bpm?

Can this problem be solved using central limit theorem?

The theorem gives us information about the means of samples not about the probability density function, if the question were "what is the probability that the average fetal heart rate of a population of $40$ people differs from the mean by more than $25$ bpm" it would have been easy to solve, but I don't really know how to approach this problem!

Is my understanding correct? and how would you solve this problem?

Comment: There is no application of the CLT needed. You have one random variable only. Basically you have to calculate $P(\mu-25<X<\mu+25)$, where $\mu=140$ and $X\sim\mathcal N(140,12^2)$

Comment: Why are we assuming that X follows a normal distrubution?

Comment: The central limit theorem says that the sampling distribution of the mean will always be normally distributed, as long as the sample size is large enough. Regardless of whether the population has a normal, Poisson, binomial, or any other distribution, the sampling distribution of the mean will be normal. So, what does this tell you about the question?

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh It is not stated explizit. But we have to know/assume a distribution. And $\mu$ and $\sigma$ are the two parameters of the normal distribution.Otherwise we cannot calculate any probability. I think the main topic is the normal distribution.

Comment: You have a situation where the mean is about equal to the variance, which suggests using the Poisson distribution.

Comment: @mmmmhmmmmmh All fine? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

We can just calculate the $Z$-score here. As our $x$ value here pertains to when the fetal heartrate differs from the mean by $\gt25$ bpm, this can be interpreted as $x=140+25=165$. Hence

\begin{align*}
Z&=\frac{x-\mu}{\sigma}\\
&=\frac{165-140}{12}\\
&=2.083\\
\end{align*}

Therefore

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{P}(X\gt165)&=\mathbb{P}(Z\gt2.083)\\
&=1-\mathbb{P}(Z\lt2.083)\\
&=1-\Phi(2.083)\\
&=1−0.98124\\
&\approx0.01876\\
\end{align*}

```
1-pnorm(2.083)
0.01862561
```

Note that you don't have enough information to calculate the Central limit theorem. We would need a sample size $n$ for a start. More information [can be found here.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/466360/318620)